# How to check if a String is in a hash map, and then give it that function

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hash

Im very rusty on Java, and this is my first time using hash maps on a project and I'm very stuck with this problem. So i have a hash map set up that has two paramers, string and operator object. How would i read in a string and give it that function. For example, I created my hash table,

private final static HashMap Ops;

```
static{
    Ops = new HashMap<>();
    Ops.put("+", new AdditionOperator());
    Ops.put("-", new SubtractionOperator());
    Ops.put("*", new MultiplyOperator());
    Ops.put("/", new DivideOperator());
    Ops.put("^", new PowerOperator());
    Ops.put("#", new PoundOperator());
    //Ops.put("!", new ExOperator());

}
```

now when i verify a string is an operator and create a newOP

**newOperator newOp = new newOperator(token);**

what kind of method can i use to essentially pass the string to the hash table and give it the values declared in its specific class.

I've been trying with the .containsKey() function, but i keep getting errors. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: which error in `.containsKey()` method?

Comment: Just use `get`.  It returns null if the requested key isn't in the map.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem `get` returns value. OP wants to check for key.

Comment: @Kaushal28 Yes, but if the key is not present, then `get` returns null.  There's no point in calling both `containsKey` and `get`.  He should just call `get`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `.containsKey()` for that.

```
if(map.containsKey("+")){
     //use +, because it is in hashmap. 
     newOperator newOp = map.get("+");
}
```